# Changing the font size of an element programmatically inside a Viewbox works weird

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, font-size, viewbox

I need to change the font size of a label programmatically. The label is located inside a Viewbox:

```xml
<Window ...
        FontSize="24"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
        WindowStyle="ThreeDBorderWindow"
        ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Grid>
        <Viewbox x:Name="vb" Stretch="Uniform">
            <Label x:Name="label1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Content="Text"/>
        </Viewbox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The font size of text inside the label is assumed to be 24. However, even if I set it in my code like this to its 'original' value in xaml:

```cs
label1.FontSize = 24;
```

it becomes smaller.

Is there a simple way to keep the ratio between the new font size and the scale factor of the Viewbox?

Comment: Why are you changing fontsize?  It seems a bit strange you have a viewbox which will scale content and alter size of that text but you also want to change size of the text. And why label? This will generate a textblock as it's content with it's text property set to "Text".

Comment: @Andy I am changing the language of element titles in my form programmatically on button click. Some words become longer or shorter, so I need to adjust the text size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to set `ViewBox.StretchDirection` property to `DownOnly`, for the label will be smaller, but not bigger:

```
<StackPanel Width="200" >
   <Label Content="Text" FontSize="24" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
   <Viewbox StretchDirection="DownOnly" Stretch="Uniform">
      <Label Content="Text" FontSize="24"/>
   </Viewbox>
   <Viewbox StretchDirection="DownOnly" Stretch="Uniform">
      <Label Content="ABCDEF EEEEE ABCDEFGJKLMNOP" FontSize="24"/>
   </Viewbox>
</StackPanel>
```

So the code results to :
[image: viewbox scaling]

Comment: This does not work for me. Actually, my label is located inside several Grids, Group Boxes, and Canvases, so it might be the reason.

Comment: Strange, in posted example it does work (I added setting `FontSize` explicitly to 24), so if text in label short, then the font size remains 24, if the text too long, then font will be scaled down. Is it not what you want? Otherwise please post a verifiable example.

Comment: Once I deleted some labels and text boxes from my xaml to demonstrate my issue, it actually started working as expected. The problem seems to lie deeper.